# How to move Objects in android automatically?

Tags: android, animation, gridview, android-animation

I am writing an application that contain a Grid Main View, in this grid view I have some `ImageViews`, and I have a `Spinner` for sorting in the `ActionBar`, and I want to implement this:

When I change the menu from the spinner menu I want to this objects move automatically in certain position, for example I have some photo and and have three categories in spinner menu, when I choose one of them, I want to fade irrelevant photos and another move to some position automatically, something like Google Keep, when you Drag & Drop a note, it will move automatically to same size in another position and coordinate on screen.

I have a link, they implement what I mean in a Website. I want to know how can I implement something like that in Android application?!

Here is the [link](http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-frostwave/portfolio-fullwidth-style-4/)!

Hit the items in the Sort Portfolio  and see the changes. I want to show this animation in android application, for some ImageViews in `GridLayout`.

Comment: Do you want to move it with some animation?

Comment: @BlazeTama please check the link , and use that sort portfolio and show the movement and animation that i mean , and then you will get what i mean